# Eclipse hides docs and dist folders

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javadoc

I successfully built a project using ANT.  I see in Windows Explorer that all the correct files were generated in the expected directories.  The bin and src folders show up in the Navigator and Project Explorer windows, but I cannot find any way to unhide the docs and dist folders.  I have tried turning off all filters and allowing all content to be displayed, but the folders are still hidden.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you refreshed the project (File / Refresh)?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally decided to delete the project (without deleting the source) and import it back into Eclipse.  All folders are now visible.

I hope this helps someone else.